# Show that two homogeneous polynomials in two variables which share no linear factors generate power of maximal ideal

Tags: polynomials, ideals

I'm trying to show that given $g$ and $h$, homogeneous polynomials in $k[x,y]$ of degrees $m$ and $n$, respectively, if $g$ and $h$ share no common linear factors, then they generate the maximal ideal of $k[x,y]$ to the $m+n-1$'st power. It is clear that they generate some power of the maximal ideal from the nullstellensatz, and it is clear that if $g = x^m$ and $h = y^n$ that they generate all monomials of degree $m+n-1$, which form a basis for $\mathfrak{m}^{m+n-1}$. However, in general I'm having trouble showing that this is true (but I suspect that it is).

$\mathbf{Edit}$: I'm trying to do exercise 5.14b in Hartshorne, and I believe this is what I have to show to prove the statement in the exercise; if perhaps I've gone astray in coming to this conclusion, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: yes, K is supposed to be algebraically closed. I'm not entirely sure how to respond to the other comment, although perhaps this is what I'm confused about. On the other hand, I believe it's fine if they generate something larger...

Comment: also, I would point out that your $g$ and $h$ aren't homogeneous (I mean, $h$ isn't), so they aren't the sort of thing I'm talking about anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an algebraist but I guess this result should be well known. Nevertheless, I found an elementary proof.

I don't assume $k$ algebraically closed. Set $I$ the ideal of $k[x, y]$ generated by
$g$ and $h$. We want to prove that $I \cap \mathfrak{m}^{m+n-1} = \mathfrak{m}^{m+n-1}$.

First, we will prove $x^{m+n-1} \in I$ and $y^{m+n-1} \in I$.
Let $G$ and $H$ the two polynomials of $k[z]$ such that
$$y^m G\Big(\frac{x}{y}\Big) = g(x,y)\ \mbox{ and }\ y^n H\Big(\frac{x}{y}\Big) = h(x, y).$$
Then $\mathrm{deg}\, G = \mathrm{deg}_h\, g$ and $\mathrm{deg}\, H = \mathrm{deg}_h\, h$ and $G$ and $H$ are relatively prime since $g$ and $h$ have no common linear factors. Thus according to the Bézout's identity, there exist $U, V \in k[z]$ such that
$$ U G + V H = 1 \mbox{ and } \mathrm{deg}\, U < \mathrm{deg}\, H,\ \ \mathrm{deg}\, V < \mathrm{deg}, G.$$
But $u = y^{n-1} U(\frac{x}{y}) \in k[x, y]$ and $v = y^{m-1} V(\frac{x}{y}) \in k[x, y]$. Hence
$$ y^{m+n-1} = u g + v h.$$
In other words, $y^{m+n-1} \in I$. By arguing with $y$ replaced by $x$, we got $x^{m+n-1} \in I$.

Now we proceed by induction on $m+n$. Assume the statement holds for any homogeneous polynomials of degree $s \leqslant m$ and $t \leqslant n$  such that $s + t \leqslant m+n-2$. If $x$ divides $g$ then $g = x f$ with $f \in k[x, y]$ homogeneous of degree $m-1$. Thus by induction hypothesis,
$$\langle f, h \rangle \cap \mathfrak{m}^{m+n-2} = \mathfrak{m}^{m+n-2}.$$
Hence for any $p, q$ such that $p+q = m + n-2$, we can find $u, v \in k[x, y]$ such that
$$ x^p y^q = u f + v h.$$
So, we get
$$ x^{p+1} y^q = u x f + x v h = u g + x v h.$$
We proved that $x^p y^q \in I$ for any $p \geqslant 1$ and $q \geqslant 0$ such that $p + q = m + n - 1$. Since $y^{m+n-1} \in I$ by the above argument, we have done in this case. Arguing similarly, we deal with the case $y \mid g$, $x \mid h$ and $y \mid h$. The last case is when $x$ and $y$ don't divide $g$ and $h$. Thus, there exist $g_1, h_1 \in k[x, y]$ homogeneous such that
$$ g = x^m + y^m + xy g_1\ \mbox{ and }\ h = x^n + y^n + xy h_1.$$
We can assume that $m \geqslant n$. If $m = n$ set $f = g - h$, otherwise set $f = g - (x^{m-n} + y^{m-n})h$. Then
$$ f = xy g_1 - xy h_1\ \mbox{ or }\ f = xy g_1 - x^{m-n}y^n - y^{m-n}x^n - x^{m-n+1}y h_1 - y^{m-n+1}x h_1.$$
So $x$ and $y$ divide $f$, $f$ and $h$ don't share a linear factor and $I = \langle f, h \rangle$. We apply the above argument to conclude.

**Remark 1:** I don't know if it is useful but the proof is completely effective. You can write easily an algorithm.

**Remark 2:** It could be interesting to investigate the higher dimension case. The following statement might hold:

> Let $f_1, \ldots, f_n \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be homogeneous polynomials of degree $m_1, \ldots, m_n$ without common zero in $\bar{k}^n-\{0\}$. Then
> $$ \langle f_1, \ldots, f_n \rangle \cap \mathfrak{m}^{m_1 + \cdots + m_n - n + 1} = \mathfrak{m}^{m_1 + \cdots + m_n - n + 1}.$$

**Edit:**
The above proposition is a consequence of properties of the Macaulay resultant. Indeed, if $f_1, \ldots, f_n \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ are homogeneous polynomials, then we can prove
$$ \mathrm{Res}(f_1, \ldots, f_n) x_1^{p_1} \cdots x_n^{p_n} \in \langle f_1, \ldots, f_n \rangle, $$
for any $p_1, \ldots, p_n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p_1 + \cdots + p_n = m_1 + \cdots + m_n - n + 1$ and $\mathrm{Res}(f_1, \ldots, f_n) \in k$ is the Macaulay resultant. But the Macaulay resultant vanishes if and only if the system has a non-zero solution.

Comment: do you know where I might be able to find a proof of the last fact? (namely, that the resultant times any monomial with proper degree is in the ideal generated by the $f_i$)

Comment: Alas, I didn't find a proper reference for this result. You can see the chapter IX of Algebra by Lang about Elimination theory, especially Lemma 3.7 where he proves the property for the generic resultant and monomial of the form $x_i^{m_1+\cdots+m_n-n+1}$. I think the general result can be deduced by the same induction scheme than in dimension 1. In [1](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-00281761), Yger proves the result in complex case using analytic residue. It seems Jacobi knew such a statement since 1835, see the 20th issue of [2](https://eudml.org/doc/183211) in latin!

Comment: I found the complete result in [3](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870896916096) Section 3.9.4, see Eq 3.9.4.3.